# Getting all rows from the table that contain the same values in some columns in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Right now I can get all values from a table called **cars** by using this single statement in CodeIgniter:

```
$this->db->get('cars')->results();
```

The problem is that I would like to select **ONLY** the rows based on the same value in the column called **slug**, which is a stored URL e.g. "very-good-car-for-sale" or "black-mustang-in-good-condition". Basically I want to find all duplicates (but I want to expand that later to the name, description etc., but my main concern for now is the slug column)

How should my DB query looks like in CodeIgniter environment to grab only duplicates, I mean rows that have the same slug at least twice in the table?

Is it possible via CI Active Record and not via a custom SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

First get IDs of records which are duplicate and then use this result as a subquery.

```
$this->db->select('`id`');
$this->db->from('cars');
$this->db->group_by('slug');
$this->db->having('count(slug) > 1');
$where_clause = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->get('cars');
$this->db->where('`id` IN ($where_clause)', NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution grabs everything that contains some string e.g. it grabs "blue-volkswagen-2001" but also "blue-volkswagen-2005" which is a different slug. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @user3041274 2 options: either add a where condition (answer updated above) OR add another having condition.

Comment: Thanks, but slug could be anything. How to do that?

Comment: Sure, use a variable like `$slug_value` instead of `'very-good-car-for-sale'` in the `where` condition, then it could be any value you want.

Comment: Wow, this seems to be partially working: `$this->db->group_by('slug')->having('count(slug) > 1')->get('cars');` I have changed `count(slug) > 2` to `count(slug) > 1` But the problem is that it selects only the first duplicated row and not the all 2 or 3 etc. How to fix that?

Comment: First get IDs of records which are duplicate and then use this result as a subquery. Try updated answer above.

Comment: I cannot use this `$this->db->where('slug', $slug_value);`. I need to check the whole database for duplicated slugs. I don't know them beforehand. The problem with your query is that by grouping it eliminate other rows and take only the first row in the group. This need to be fixed somehow.

Comment: Remove the where condition, it will check for all duplicates. I have changed the approach in my answer above, try it, it will get all duplicate rows

Comment: I have tried this code: http://pastebin.com/HgFsW8M9 but it's still not working and the code broke my site ;(.  guess the php is wrong. I have id column called id, do I need to escape it too with `?

Comment: yes, since `id` is reserved keyword so you have to enclose it in `

Comment: I don't hink the queries here in the pastebin link, could you ceck it please? It's breaking my site. probably some execution error.

Comment: I would not be able to check the code at this moment. Most probably there is a minor PHP syntax issue somewhere. However, the general idea I am trying to convey is that make a sub query to get IDs of duplicate records using group by. Then execute main query to get full records based on the IDs you get earlier. Hope it helps

Comment: I don't think it will work. It will be tha same as the first thing. Thanks anyway.